# JQuery UI .Sortable jumps when moving li at bottom of overflow

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have looked through multiple similar cases of this JQueryUI .sortable li move jump but nothing seems to be similar. I have a dynamic list that grows and shrinks as users add and remove items. If it is kept at the top it moves the items smoothly. As soon as I put it into a overflow when you scroll all the way to the bottom and move a list item the list item jumps as if it sticks to the bottom of the list. You could in some cases lose the list item entirely and have to move the mouse around a few times for it to become visible again. I am assuming it has something to do with the relative height of the container it is in?

```js
// find elements
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sortable_List').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.sortable_List {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.list_item {
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <ul class='sortable_List'>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
    <li class='list_item'>This is a List Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have created a JSfiddle as an example: https://jsfiddle.net/Kradenko/8L47rc05/13/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sortable list needs a fixed height when sorting in a scrollable container.

Set the fixed height during a mousedown function, then reset the height to auto during the sortable start function.

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Souleste/09mp8k4z/).

```
// find elements
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.sortable_List').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).height($(this).height());
  }).sortable({
    axis: 'y',    
    start: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).height('auto');
    }
  });

});
```

I don't quite understand *why* this works, but I know that to get certain css to work properly you will sometimes need to have fixed heights on elements rather than auto heights, so think of it like that.

Comment: Thank you! I think this did the trick! I have several places I need to add this. I suspected that it wasn't able to determine the height. Thanks!